# Winforms to ASP.net migration with MVC pattern : how to manage events?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, design-patterns

I'm creating an application in C#/WinForms which could be migrated to a Web application in the near future, so I'm trying to figure out the best pattern to use.

My question is what would be the best way to manage events? Personally, I can think of two possible solutions:

**First one:**

`Interface`

```
public interface IAttributionView
{
    event ButtonClicked ControllerTestEvent;
}
```

`Form`

```
public delegate void ButtonClicked();    
public partial class AttributionFrm : Form,IAttributionView
{
    public event ButtonClicked ControllerTestEvent;

    public AttributionFrm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void butTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ControllerTestEvent();
    }
}
```

`Controller`

```
public class AttributionController
{
    private IAttributionView _view;

    public AttributionController(IAttributionView view)
    {
        _view = view;
        view.ButtonClicked += new ButtonClicked(Test);
    }

    private void Test()
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

**Second one:**

`Form`

```
public partial class AttributionFrm : Form,IAttributionView
{
    private AttributionController _controller;

    public AttributionFrm(AttributionController controller)
    {
        _controller=controller;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void butTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _controller.Test();
    }
}
```

`Controller`

```
public class AttributionController
{
    private IAttributionView _view;

    public AttributionController(IAttributionView view)
    {
        _view = view;
    }

    private void Test()
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

I don't know ASP.net at all, that's the reason why I would like to know from your opinion and experience what is the best approach to achieve that (simplicity of adaptation, complexity of code, or whatever)?

Many thanks.

Comment: Juan's answer is good, but it's important to emphasise that they really are not equivalent when it comes down to the actual UX. The real problem is how users "experience" their UI workflow in a browser compared with a Windows Desktop app.  Depending on the complexity of the app, and assuming the app is re-created using just static webpages, it can involve users endlessly waiting for pages to load.  If you're implementing anything more complex than basic CRUD functionality, I'd be careful about using Razor pages and think about how to recreate the UI using a framework such as Angular instead

Comment: Think about it this way: Windows Forms application is your front-end. So some of the event handlers that you have, are event handlers for UI logic and they are not business logic. For example if you have loaded "States" and "Cities" and by selecting a state from a combo box, you show cities of that state, then `SelectedIndexChanged` method of the combo box is a front-end event and you should not to convert it to an action. But the methods that loads data for you, is an action. So First of all think about it: How can you make your application service-oriented. This will answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Events are a paradigm of connected environments. The web is disconnected. There are no events in `http` posts, only requests and responses.

Going to ASP.NET with MVC requires a change in your framework of thinking.

You are now dealing with posts that target a particular `action` which is managed by a `controller`.

If you think about it this way, your `event` can be mapped to an action that in turn executes the code that you intend to encapsulate.

These two would then become equivalent:

```
//Winforms
private void butTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Your code here
}

//MVC
public ActionResult Test()
{
    //Your code here 
}
```

The corresponding button `<input type="submit" value="Click here to Test">` would be inside a form tag that submits an `http` request to `/Attribution/Test`.

Comment: I don't really understand. I have quickly read some tutos and I saw there were controls and events in ASP.net. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Gadsweb: You specifically mentioned MVC. The other, older pattern is called WebForms and it does **simulate** events. I would not recommend it though.

Comment: Ok it was a quick overview, I didn't catch this difference. Now it's a little bit clear for me. At this point it's better to reference my "controller" in the form and call the method invoked by an event. Indeed catching event in the controller is more work and complexity. Thanks for your well considered advice.